# How to decompose $\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2}$ into partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Good Day.

I was trying to decompose $$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2}$$ into partial fractions.

$$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2} = \frac{A}{1 + x} + \frac{B}{(1 - x)^2}$$
$$1 = A(1 - x)^ 2 + B(1 + x)$$
Substitute $x = 1$, $$B = \frac{1}{2}$$
Substitute $x = -1$, $$A = \frac{1}{4}$$

However, $$\frac{1}{4(1 + x)} + \frac{1}{2 (1 - x)^2}$$ doesn't seem to equal $$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2}$$

How do we decompose this into partial fractions?

Thanks

Comment: Should be: $$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2} = \frac{A}{1 + x} + \frac{B}{(1 - x)}+ \frac{C}{(1 - x)^2}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)^{2}}=\dfrac{\frac14}{1+x}+\dfrac{\frac34-\frac14x}{(1-x)^{2}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form you chose
$$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2} = \frac{A}{1 + x} + \frac{B}{(1 - x)^2}$$
is not general enough - your calculation proves this. It is clear apriori, since why should $1$ be expressible in the form $A(1-x)^2 + B(1+x)$? There are $3$ constraints (the coefficient of $x^2$ should be $0$, as well as that of $x$, and the constant term should be $1$), but you've allowed only $2$ degrees of freedom $A,B$.

The general form which allows decomposing any fraction into partial fractions can be found e.g. [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) (see specifically the examples where it is the easiest to understand it).

Specifically for your problem, the form you should try to decompose into is

$$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2} = \frac{A}{1 + x} + \frac{B}{1 - x} + \frac{C}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

try this one $$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2} = \frac{A}{1 + x} + \frac{Bx+C}{(1 - x)^2}
$$ and find $A,B,C$

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint given by @GEdgar, notice that
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)^{2}}=\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{(1-x)^{2}} +\frac{C}{1+x}.$$
Solving, we get
$$1=A(x^{2}-1)+B(x+1)+C(x-1)^{2}$$
Equality coefficients, we have
$$\begin{cases}-A+B+C=1,\\  0A+B-2C=0,\\A+0B+C=0\end{cases}$$
Solving the system equations, we get
$$\left(A,B,C\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}\right).$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)^{2}}=\frac{-1/4}{1-x}+\frac{1/2}{(1-x)^{2}} +\frac{1/4}{1+x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A direct splitting as follows is also possible and sometimes quite quick:

\begin{eqnarray*} \color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2}}
& = & \frac{1+x-x}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2} \\
& = & \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{1-x -1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2} \\
& = & \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)} \color{blue}{- \frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence,

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{\color{blue}{2}}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2}
& = & \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac 12\frac{1+x+1-x}{(1 + x)(1 - x)}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

So, you get

$$\frac{1}{(1 + x)(1 - x)^2}=\frac 12 \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac 14 \frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac 14 \frac{1}{1 + x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$1=\frac{(1+x)+(1-x)}2.$$ This should make the exercise trivial.